# What is wrong with check_referrer function that i use for CSFR/XSFR protection?

Tags: regex, preg-replace, strpos

i have his code in php file and i want to know how that code work. can you please explain this to me by an example (all code)?

```
if (strpos(preg_replace('/^.+:\/\/(www\.)?/','',$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']).'/',preg_replace('/^.+:\/\/(www\.)?/','',$my_base_url))!==0)
```

what is the meaning of

```
'/^.+:\/\/(www\.)?/'
```

in 1st () ?

the all fuction code :

```
function check_referrer($post_url=false){
    global $my_base_url, $my_website_base, $xsfr_first_page, $_GET, $_POST;

    if (sizeof($_GET)>0 || sizeof($_POST)>0)
    {

        if ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])
        {
            $base = $my_website_base;

            if (!$base) $base = '/';
            $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] = sanitize($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],3);

            // update checks if HTTP_REFERER and posted url are the same!
            if(strpos(urldecode($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']),$post_url)!==false) return true;


            //if (strpos(preg_replace('/^.+:\/\/(www\.)?/','',$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']).'/',preg_replace('/^.+:\/\/(www\.)?/','',$my_base_url).$base)!==0)
            if (strpos(preg_replace('/^.+:\/\/(www\.)?/','',$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']).'/',preg_replace('/^.+:\/\/(www\.)?/','',$my_base_url))!==0)
            {
                unset($_SESSION['xsfr']);
                $wrongurlrefforme=urldecode($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
                die("");
            }
        }
        elseif ($xsfr_first_page)
        {
            unset($_SESSION['xsfr']);
            die("");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `^` means start of line, `.+` means 1 or more characters, `:` is literal `:`, `\/\/` is two slashes but needed to be escaped, `(www\.)` means the literal `www.` is optional `(...)`. It can match `http://www.`, `http://`, `https://www.`, ftp://`.

Comment: Do you really mean `!==`? You probably meant `!=`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  While kind folk are trying to help you, please note that this question does not meet the guidelines for questions  here.   See item #1 [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: OK, i am sorry, my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'/^.+:\/\/(www\.)?/'` is a regular expression.

It means:

```
 /^        "Starting from the beginning of the string..."
  .+        "... match any string that has at least one character"
  :\/\/     "... followed by a colon followed by two foward slashes"
  (www\.)?/ "... and if there is 'www.' after those, call that "group one""
```

So ...

`preg_replace('/^.+:\/\/(www\.)?/','',$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])`

means

"look in the 'HTTP_REFERER' element of the $_SERVER array, and see if it matches the description above.  If it does, replace the 'www.' part of it with nothing."

Whatever the result of that is, becomes the first argument to `strpos()`.

The second argument to `strpos()` is constructed similarly.

Then `strpos()` tells you where the second string is found in the first.   Thus the `if` statement is asking if the output of `strpos()` is the same value and type as zero.

A safer comparison would be `!=`, because you don't care about the types.

Comment: thanks very much. do you see any error in this code? (to work badly?)

Comment: @Support - Your code went wrong because you are comparing the output of `strpos()` with `0` but you are using wrong operator `!==`. Use `!=` instead.

Comment: i have this code in function for (CSFR/XSFR protection). but this not work fine. can you tell me what is wrong with this line?

Comment: did you means : i shuold change "!==" via "!=" ?

Answer (score 0):

That is a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Regular_expression).  For example, it will match `http://www.`

Comment: match  http:// www.   with what?

Comment: not exactly. preg_replace replaces the finding of `http://www.` so `http://www.example.org` will be `example.org`

Comment: thanks for your great help, can you tell me about all that code ? thanks a lot